# ESP32 SPI Flash

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I am trying to utilize the flash available on my esp32. Can anyone please help me to do this? I have already tried the following:

```
esp_flash_t *chip;
esp_flash_init(*chip);
```

I am not importing any spi flash related libraries. The following error is outputted on build by ESP-IDF:

```
implicit declaration of function 'esp_flash_init'
```

Is it required to import any libraries for the use of esp32 flash?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What `#include` did you write? I think you need `esp_flash.h` for that.

Comment: It sounds as if you haven't included the required header file mentioned in the documentation. And your use of the `esp_flash_t` struct is also incorrect. You have to allocate it on the stack and then pass it's address to the function. Having said that: None of this is needed for using the typical flash memory on a ESP32. What exactly are you trying to do?